# What's a metaphor/idiom for when someone asks for help with a problem that you also have?

Tags: phrases, idioms, metaphors

To elaborate, the implication is that you can't help them, because if you knew how to, you wouldn't be in the situation yourself.

I could've sworn I heard there was already an established phrase for this, something about a drowning man?

If not, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Partners in crime.

Answer (score 1):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-me-about-it)
>
> **tell me about it!**: informal
>
> used to say that you feel the same way or have had the same experience:
> "*He's driving me crazy with his stupid jokes." "Tell me about it!*"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for *the blind leading the blind*:

> A situation in which incompetent or ignorant people are guided or
> taught by an equally incompetent or ignorant person.
>   <sub>*Don't
> ask me to tutor someone in algebra because it would be the blind
> leading the blind.*</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [The Free Dictionary
> Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+blind+leading+the+blind)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

"(I'm) in the same boat"

This is the phrase I would use in your situation.

[Phrases Org give this origin](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-the-same-boat.html):

> 'In the same boat' originated in 16th century Britain. When Thomas Hudson translated Du Bartas' Historie of Judith in 1584 he formed a metaphor that equated being 'in the same boat' with 'having the same fate':
>
> Haue ye paine? so likewise paine haue we: For in one bote we both imbarked be.
>
> ...
>
> The metaphor clearly alludes to the fact that one cannot get off a boat once it is under way and alludes to people who are together in a boat sharing the same fate, whether they choose to or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying "If I only knew!" is

> That's the sixty-four-thousand-dollar / million-dollar question.

**the sixty-four-thousand-dollar question**

> A question that is very important and difficult or complex to answer.
> [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/64000+dollar+question)

> A very important question that is very difficult to answer.
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/the-64-000-dollar-question)

**million-dollar question**

> A crucial or essential question. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/million-dollar_question)